# Heat transfer of a monatomic ideal gas at room temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

[image]

I have done parts a) and b) but have been stuck on c) for hours I have tried to come up with a formula but can’t come up with a reasonable one - I can’t even see how it is possible. Any help would be much appreciated!!! Thanks

Comment: How can you have heat being transferred if the compression takes place adiabatically?

Comment: I think they want a general formula for all compression processes (and then show that it works by showing it yields Q=0 for an adiabatic process) but I don’t see how that’s possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think they mean an isothermal process. Then the heat transfer is just equal and opposite to the work because the total energy is constant.